# Netflix-desktop app no longer exists in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, netflix-desktop

After a fresh install of 14.04 I  cannot get the netflix-desktop app. I type in the proper code and I get "E: Unable to Locate Package netflix-desktop". Is it no longer available? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's available via a PPA. You need to add that PPA first.

https://launchpad.net/~ehoover/+archive/ubuntu/compholio

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: @Sir_Yoshi: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-ppa.html

Comment: Thank you it is now working and as usual it is faster than windows